# inapp purchases server setup

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am a new developer and am quite proud that I have figured out the basics of iOS programing and have made a solid app. Now I want to add really basic non-consumable in-app purchases to my app. I have read through apple's programing guide for inApp purchases and a couple tutorials including:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

I can follow the iOS coding but I have no idea how to set up a server to host the data. Are there any good resources or tutorials that explain how to setup the server and explain the code needed to communicate with and organize the data from application and Apple? I am looking for even basic information such as what type of servers and hosts are recommended for in-app purchases (ASW EC2??)?

- Basically what is needed exactly (explained for a noob) to set up the server aspect of IAP.

Considering I don't know what I am doing should I use a 3rd party system like http://urbanairship.com/products/in-app-purchase/

Has anyone had success with this or can recommend another?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a basic in app purchase, don't set a server up.

If do everything on apple's server, and manage it through iTunes connect, as explained in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the in-app purchases involving a third party (non-apple) server are a more advanced topic.  You should really specify what you want this in-app purchase to do first.  If it's something basic like "remove advertisements" (a popular one lately) then you don't need your own server.

KIS principle: Keep It Simple

Comment: KIS absolutely.  The in-app purchases are fairly large audio files and there are a number of them.  I want the user to be able to choose which ones they want to purchase.  In order to avoid one massive application with all the files built in, it seems like I need the server method.  Or can I do that using iTunes connect?

Comment: I would say in this case, yes, you do need the server solution, and given your limited abilities here... probably better to outsource that part of it.  You can always redo your app later to move to a better/cheaper solution, but if you have something ready to sell now, go with the ready-to-go solution, and worry about the server complexity another day.